# Does any subset of $[0,1]$ have a well-defined Lebesgue Measure? No.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

New comer to measure theory!  I'm struggling to wrap my head around this concept...

Referring to Lebesgue Measures!

Could someone provide a concrete example of a set in the interval $[0,1]$ such that the probability of choosing a point in that set is not well defined?

Comment: Do you mean find a subset of $[0,1]$ such that its points are not Lebesgue measurable? Or do you mean find $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ such that (some) points are not measurable?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a subset of $[0,1]$ that is not Lebesgue measurable.  If so, the link is a duplicate.  If not, please explain the difference and we can work on it.

Comment: @Ennar Ah i mean to say a subset of [0,1] such that its points are not Lebesgue measurable

Comment: I agree with Ross, you are probably looking for non-measurable set. Note that $\{x\}$ is always Lebesgue measurable with measure $0$, so "its points are not Lebesgue measurable" is probably not what you really want.